# Writing a Bazaar plugin - register command?

Tags: plugins, bazaar

I'm having a problem with writing my Bazaar plugin.

I've been trying a few different things, and this is the current state of my file:

```
''' Testing Bzr plugins '''                                                     
from bzrlib.commands import Command, register_command                           

version_info = (0,0,1, 'dev')                                                   

class cmd_test_foo(Command):                                                    
    ''' Testing is painful. '''                                                 

    def run(self):                                                              
        print "hi"                                                

register_command(cmd_test_foo)
```

Here's what happens when I try to execute my command:

```
$bzr test-foo
hi
bzr: ERROR: unknown command "test-foo"
```

So that's really weird - it's obviously running my command, but tells me it's unknown?

Are there any good sources for plugin examples? I've looked at the `builtins.py` as suggested [here](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/plugins/en/plugin-development.html) but nothing there seemed to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I couldn't find any real information on this error on the web or SO, I decided I should post and answer my own question.

When Bazaar imports a plugin it creates a .pyc file just like normally importing from Python. If something magical happens - like editing it in one directory and forgetting to copy it, and then creating a symlink - it will never import the modifications. The `register_command(cmd_test_foo)` call is necessary for bazaar to register the command, where cmd_test_foo is your command name. When you call bzr help commands it will also show up like so:

```
$ bzr help commands
... (snip commands)
test-foo         Testing is painful.  [testCmd]
... (snip other commands)
```

and also

```
$ bzr plugins
testCmd 0.0.1.dev
    Testing Bzr plugins
```

of course on that last one you'll also see any other plugins you may have installed.